# Sort matlab matrix rows based on function

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

Let's say I have a **Nx3** matrix **M**.

Consider, for example, a function **Map(v)** that receives as input a **1x3 array** and returns a **double**.

How can I sort the rows of **M** so that the rows with smallest **Map** should come first?

That is, the row **i** should be the first if `Map(M(i,:)) ≤ Map(M(j,:))` for all `1 ≤ j ≤ N` and `j ≠ i` ?

example:

```
M = |1 2 3|
    |4 5 6|
    |7 8 9|

Map(v){
    if (v(1) == 1 && v(2) == 2 && v(3) == 3) return 2
    if (v(1) == 4 && v(2) == 5 && v(3) == 6) return 3
    if (v(1) == 7 && v(2) == 8 && v(3) == 9) return 1
}
```

So the sorting should leave M like this:

```
M = |7 8 9|
    |1 2 3|
    |4 5 6|
```

Comment: use `[~,I]=sort(your_sum)` to get indices in `I`. `M(I,:)` is your desired output. Check [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)

Comment: @brainkz what does `[~,I]=sort(your_sum)` mean?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)

Comment: @Daniel by `your_sum` I meant `Sum(a,b,c)`, a vector that you will use for sorting.

Comment: @brainkz it didn't work, I'm new to matlab and I don't know what you mean with `[~,I]` and how would `[~,I] = sort(Sum)` sort some thing

Answer (score 0):

```
% initialize an N-by-3 matrix where N=10...
M = [
  1 0 3;
  4 2 2;
  0 1 0;
  7 5 6;
  3 3 8;
  2 1 4;
  0 0 6;
  3 1 2;
  5 0 0;
  1 6 2
];

% sum its rows...
M_sum = sum(M,2);

% sort the vector of sums in ascending order...
[~,idx] = sort(M_sum);

% reorder the matrix rows based on the sorting result...
M = M(idx,:);
```

Comment: will this work if function is not sum, but for example, any mapping `Map(a,b,c)` ?

Comment: What di you mean with mapping? It depends, if it produces a vector with a value for each row, yes, otherwise I doubt.

Comment: As I said, as long as your map function returns a column vector the code is unchanged: M_mapped = map(M); [~,idx] = sort(M_mapped); [~,idx] = sort(M_sum);

Comment: no, but it helped me to understand a little bit, I ended up using sortrow method and was able to solve it with a bit more code